# How to get EditText.mesaure to return a size large enough to contain text content?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to get a `EditText` to be large enough for the content it contains, but `measure` just always seems to it keeping the size it currently has.

> - I have multiple lines of text
> - I pass a makeMeasureSpec(w, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) for the width, and UNSPECIFIED for the height to the `measure` function
> - I use getMeasuredHeight() to obtain the resulting height, which always returns the current height
> - I've tried adding LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT,WRAP_CONTENT) to the View but it didn't change the result

How can I get the `EditText` to report a size that is large enough to contain the text inside of it?

Comment: Can you post some code? My hunch is that you're calling `getMeasuredHeight()` before the View has an opportunity to resize. Have you tried setting up a `OnGlobalLayoutListener`?

Comment: Rather than using `LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT,WRAP_CONTENT)` have you tried specifying `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in the XML?

Comment: Why would I need to wait for a resize before calling `getMeasureHeight()`? It's supposed to return the resulting size of `measure` (which it does for other controls at least).

Comment: I can't provide code since I'm not working directly in XML or Java but via an external interface. I also don't want `match_parent` for width since I also need to determine the width of the control in other layout scenarios.

Comment: I'd need to see some code, but changes to a View aren't necessarily reflected immediately. Sometimes they're placed in a queue to be processed later. That's why you use an `OnGlobalLayoutListener`. It's from in there that you call `getMeasuredHeight`.